# What does 'overt NP' mean?

Tags: syntax, cases, noun-phrases

I just started studying syntax, and I am a little lost in terminology. Would someone please explain to me what does overt NP stand for?

Comment: Are you asking about the "overt" part or the "NP" part?

Comment: Can you give us the sentence that the term was used in please, Future Linguist? [Welcome to Linguistics, btw!]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers

Answer (score 7):

NP is short for *noun phrase*. You'll also see *VP, PP, AdvP, AdjP* which stand in for *verb phrase, preposition(al) phrase, adverb phrase* and *adjective phrase*.

Some generativist linguists use the term DP instead of NP as they view a string like *the dog* as having the determiner *the* as the head of the phrase and the noun *dog* as a complement. (Both of these terms cover the use of pronouns.)

When speaking, people usually spell those abbreviations out. So they usually say "en pee" not "noun phrase" for NP and so on.

It's not  possible to tell you *precisely* what an ***overt*** NP is out of context. However, presumably there is some sort of unrealised or silent type of NP that it is being contrasted with. So, essentially, an 'overt' NP is just a normal, common garden NP that you can hear (or see).

The sort of situation where you might see a silent/phonologically empty/ covert/implied/null NP is when a clause doesn't have an expressed subject:

- Pinch yourself!
- It's important to look after yourself

In the examples above the verb *pinch* doesn't have an overt subject, and neither does the infinitival string *to look after yourself.* However, it could be postulated that they both have some kind of unexpressed NP/DP subject. Some evidence for this might be that they both have reflexive pronouns as dependents. We normally expect to see reflexive pronouns when they are coreferential with a subject NP of some sort.

- Bob pinched himself.

To illustrate, in the example above, the subject, *Bob*, and the object, *himself*, both refer to the same person.

Comment: There are also those languages which mark subjects and other constituents on the verb, as affixes (or otherwise). In such cases, something like an object might be an affix or an overt NP (or both, depending on the language).